# Bash move file to folder of same name

Tags: bash, rename

I apologize in advance if I am posting this in the wrong location, I am very new to scripting let alone stackoverflow:

I have a number of files ending in `.conf` in the same directory as a number of folders with the same names without the `.conf` extension. For example, my directory looks like this:

```
136
136.conf
139
139.conf
...
```

I would like to move the `.conf` files into their corresponding folder with a loop. I thought I could do this:

```
for f in *.conf; do
    dir=${f:0:13}
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

but I am obviously doing something incorrectly. I would greatly appreciate anyone's help with this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by cutting string at position 13 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Bash parameter expansion to derive the directory name by removing the extension (anything that follows the `.`):

```
for f in *.conf; do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue # skip if not regular file
  dir="${f%.*}"
  mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

This is a little better than the substring approach since we make no assumption on the length of the filename or directory name.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work properly when the filename contains a 2nd period (.).